# Android Upnp MediaController

Tags: android, upnp, mediacontroller, windows-media-server

i have a upnp-media server in my tablet, and i want to control my tv(samsung) with my tablet. I have done the media server, and i can see the audio,video and images file in my tv but I cant control it with the tablet, only with the remotee control of the tv. I want to control it also with the tablet. Any of you have any example or any tutorial to show me how to send service to tv, or how can i control the tv with the tablet.
Thank you
I am programming in java on android platform.

Comment: Which libarary did you used to make Mediaserver?

Answer (score 1):

Your tv obviously functions as a UPnP control point if it can discover and manipulate media servers.  You'll need to check whether it also acts as a UPnP device if you want to send it commands from your tablet.

The easiest way to do this is to see what devices you have on your network.  You may be able to do this from your tablet using an [existing app](https://market.android.com/details?id=cx.hoohol.silanoid&hl=en).  Or you could do it from Windows using [Intel Device Spy](http://opentools.homeip.net/dev-tools-for-upnp).

If your tv appears, the services available to control it will be displayed and will probably be documented at the [UPnP forum](http://upnp.org/sdcps-and-certification/standards/).  If your tv doesn't appear in the list of devices, you won't be able to control it from a UPnP control point.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried for samusung TV . But media Rendererslike TV  do support AVTransport service and
You can follow [this](http://teleal.org/projects/cling/support/manual/cling-support-manual.html#chapter.MediaRenderer) guide of Cling to implement the controller. You can also see Rendering control service to update volume, brightness etc.

Answer (score 0):

(DISCLAIMER: I'm personally involved in developing the free and open source code linked below)

This C code cross-compiles for ARM and Mips targets
http://syncstarter.org/avremote

```
git clone git://code.dyne.org/avremote.git
```

it can detect and send AVTransport messages to devices on the local network, things like play, stop, pause and seek, from a commandline terminal. Could be a start, still lacks an interface.

I wrote it to control video devices from console terminals and scripts.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question that was asked.